# Set User-Agent when using XmlTextReader

Tags: .net, xml

Is it possible to set the User-Agent string when making an HTTP request with XmlTextReader?  If so, how might I go about doing that?

I am using VB.NET with the .NET 2.0 runtime, but can read your C# suggestions just fine.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should not use `XmlTextReader` at all. Use `XmlReader.Create`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the `WebRequest` or `WebClient` classes to manually download the content; they allow you to set headers.

**EDIT**: For example:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "...";
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(responseStream)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: it would be good if you could show an example of WebRequest used with XmlReader.Create.

Comment: [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1): "*We don't recommend that you use HttpWebRequest for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class*". `HttpClient` then tries to use the best available transport. Headers can be set once for all subsequent requests, using property `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` of type [HttpRequestHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders?view=netcore-3.1)